# Using .next() to select div with specific class

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to make some div's visible on mouseover, but the code which I expect should work isn't working. Perhaps I'm using next() incorrectly? I use the same type of thing successfully elsewhere, so I'm a little unsure what the issue is.

**[FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/pN9ff/43/)**

Code:

---

```
$(".clause").mouseenter(function() {

    /* NOT WORKING */
    $(this).next("div.drawer-arrow").css("display","block");
    $(this).next("div.drawerBottom").css("display","block");

    $(".clause").css("border-bottom-right-radius", "0px");
    $(".clause").css("border-bottom-left-radius", "0px");

}).mouseleave(function(){

    /* NOT WORKING */
    $(this).next("div.drawer-arrow").css("display","none");
    $(this).next("div.drawerBottom").css("display","none");

    $(".clause").css("border-bottom-right-radius", "3px");
    $(".clause").css("border-bottom-left-radius", "3px"); 

});

$(".clause").click(function() {
    $(".clause").css("box-shadow", "none");

    /* WORKING */
    var tmp = $(this).next("div.drawer");
    if(tmp.is(":hidden")) {
        tmp.slideDown('2s');
        $(this).css("box-shadow", "0px 3px 5px #AAA");
    }
    else {
        tmp.slideUp('2s');
    }
});
```

Comment: So what does not work? The js fiddle example works fine. PS: If you give a link to jsfiddle, do not post your code again ..

Comment: I was told by a mod last time that I should always post code, regardless if I have a Fiddle or not :/

Basically, it is not displaying the .drawerBottom and .drawer-arrow divs when I hover over the .clause div.

Comment: @TobiasSpringer - Posting only a fiddle to the code is generally frowned on; he should have some code in the question. However, if he links to a fiddle, he should post only a small amount of code.

Comment: @Jon - You are correct, you should always post code. Just try to narrow it down next time. 5-10 lines is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: You should also count the number of steps you take on the Sabbath. Really people? We're going to be this anal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$(this).next().next('.drawer-arrow').css("display","block");
$(this).next().next().next('.drawerBottom').css("display","block");
```

The extra `.next()` will select the `<div class="drawer">` element, next one more time will get `drawer-arrow`, then again to get `drawerBottom`

**EDIT:**

Dropping through elements with `.next()` multiple times may be less optimal vs changing markup to group the query sections. You might consider re-structuring the markup so a simpler selector could be used:

```
<div class="queryGroup">
    <div class="clause">...</div>
    <div class="drawer">...</div>
    <div class="drawer-arrow"></div>
    <div class="drawerBottom"></div>
</div>
```

The `.clause` `mouseenter` event could then be something like:

```
var $this = $(this); // cache this as a jQuery object

$this.nextAll('.drawer-arrow').show();
$this.nextAll('.drawerBottom').show();

...
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the explanation, too! Makes sense as to why it works.

Comment: I had considered doing this and probably will with your suggestion. Later on, I'll be grouping queries, so it would be best to have a structure like this. Thanks, md.

Answer (score 1):

Use nextAll() in place of next(). Next() just check for the next element which in your case is not of class your are targeting.

Comment: Close, but I only want the bottom of the drawer to display for the clause that I'm hovering over. This will show all drawer bottoms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next all and combine both selectors - .next() only looks at the element that is directly after the current element.  .nextAll will find all siblings after the current element that matches the selector.

```
$(".clause").mouseenter(function() {    
    $(this).nextAll("div.drawer-arrow:first,div.drawerBottom:first").show();    
    $(".clause").css("border-bottom-right-radius", "0px")
                .css("border-bottom-left-radius", "0px");

}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).nextAll("div.drawer-arrow:first,div.drawerBottom:first").hide();    
    $(".clause").css("border-bottom-right-radius", "3px")
                .css("border-bottom-left-radius", "3px");     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/5dBsq/

Answer (score 1):

try using `.nextAll()`

```
$(this).nextAll('.drawer-arrow').first().css("display","block");
```

`.next()` will only select the element if it matches the selector.( Otherwise it will return an empty selector) ..

you can combine this with `.first()` which will get the first element instead of all the elements with that class

In such cases it is better to use `.nextAll()` when you do not know the number of sibling in between the current and the next element..